# How can I put words inside a list into new lists based on their index?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to parse a text file's lines so that I can then separate the words into four fields.

The data looks like this:

```
Luci,32,4556,22
Mark,1623,12,321
Mary,1233,443,66
```

My intention is to classify the respective columns like this: 'name', 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'. This way I can manipulate each column later.

My code so far is like this but I get: "IndexError: string index out of range":

```
for line in f:
   line=line.strip()
   index = line.split(',')
               
   for line in index:
       name = line[0].strip()
       tag1 = line[1].strip()
       tag2 = line[2].strip()
       tag3 = line[3].strip()
```

I don't know if there's a better way to do this without using a list but what I need is to get the columns' into 'fields' so I can use them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused yourself by reusing your variable names, but the real problem is that "index" is already split up into tokens.  So, `line[0].strip()` is actually the first CHARACTER of the first field.  And you don't need to strip the fields; there aren't any embedded spaces in your fields.

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    name,tag1,tag2,tag3 = line.split(',')
```

HOWEVER, it is usually smarter to leave the individual fields in a list, so you can process them in bulk later.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
with open(filename) as file:
    name = []
    tag1 = []
    tag2 = []
    tag3 = []
    f = file.readlines()
    f = [x.strip() for x in f]
    for line in f:
        name.append(line.split(',')[0])
        tag1.append(line.split(',')[1])
        tag2.append(line.split(',')[2])
        tag3.append(line.split(',')[3])
```